# Run independent `PythonScriptStep` steps in parallel

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

In my pipeline multiple steps are independent and so I would like them to run in parallel based on input dependencies.

As the compute I use has multiple nodes I would have expected this to be the default.

For example:

[image]

All 3 upper steps should run in parallel, then both `finetune` steps in parallel as soon as their inputs are satisfied and the same for `rgb_test`.

Currently only 1 step runs at a time, the other are `Queued`.

Comment: does this still happen?

Comment: Yes but it seems that it's due to the vCPU quota. I'm having it increased to confirm and I'll report here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being because of vCPU quota.

After increasing the quota, parallel tasks can run at the same time as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is weird! Are you sure your compute target's `max_nodes` is at least 3?